# install display on raspbarrypi 4 didnt work

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, display

i had the lite version installed of Raspberry os on my pi 4 - and now I followed this tutorial https://raspberrytips.com/upgrade-raspbian-lite-to-desktop/ to installing a display enviorment -  "kde-plasma-desktop"
Everything is installed and the pi is rebooted, but I cant connent via RDP with my MobaXTerm

Comment: Did you install and activate an RDP server on your Pi?

Comment: I only follow the tutorial and installed the kde desktop. Or i set up a new Pi os with desktop enviorment. but how can I change later the pixel desktop to kde

Comment: look at the code i postet below @Dirk